# Sails.js Skipper: receiving an object parameter through body-parser from PHP-style input fields array

Tags: sails.js

the form on the view.ejs side:

```
<header>Dates</header>
<div>
    <div>
        <label>Draft: </label>
        <input  name="timestamp[draft]" type="text"
            value="<%= book.related('timestamp').get('draft') %>">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Publish: </label>
        <input  name="timestamp[publish]" type="text"
            value="<%= book.related('timestamp').get('publish') %>">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Amend: </label>
        <input  name="timestamp[amend]" type="text"
            value="<%= book.related('timestamp').get('amend') %>">
    </div>
</div>
```

on the action2 side:

```
module.exports = {
    friendlyName: 'Update',
    description: 'Updates whatever changes made to the book',
    inputs: {
        id: {
            type: 'number',
        },
        book_type: {
            type: 'string',
        },
        timestamp: {type: ‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️},
    },
```

I have been trying to achieve this via `string` or `'ref'` as suggested by the error that came out in the terminal but no success!

Answer (score 0):

It is `'ref'` not `['ref']`

Check the docs:
[https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/helpers#?inputs](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/helpers#?inputs)

Comment: If you are not sure, then in my opinion, you should have given a comment rather than an answer, so as to avoid downvotes...

Comment: Yours and @Gourav are both interesting suggestions. I'll reflect your suggestion in the question, because it still remains open.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, I was coming form a PHP background and Node.js community isn't as heavily invested in replicating/covering [standard PHP community conventions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php) by default.

I couldn't figure out how the Sails's team body-parser: [Skipper](https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper) is meant to work, especially as on the Github page both the ability to raise issues or a thorough documentation and comparison with alternative solutions were missing.

I think Skipper should be a promising library, given the SailsJS quality and design, however, for the time being, I ended up going for another multiple-part supporting library suggested by [express body-parsers](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser):

- busboy and connect-busboy
- multiparty and connect-multiparty
- formidable
- multer

I ended up with [formidable](https://github.com/node-formidable/formidable) – without this choice actually repressing an analysis for which library does this job and better than the other; Even formidable [had bugs](https://github.com/node-formidable/formidable/issues/620) when it came to processing this convention, however, [we fixed it](https://github.com/node-formidable/formidable/pull/621).

PS. This is a personal report of progress, in case you're facing similar issues moving from a  PHP based backend to Sails.js; However, perhaps someone in the future could elaborate more on Skipper and etc.